# Need to access Parent Field

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using Sitecore 9.0 and DEF 2.0.1, imagine I am processing this json:

```
{

  "name": "XXX",
  "id" : "1234,
  "childobject": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "YYY",
      "type": "AAA"

    },
    {
      "id" : "2"
      "name": "FFF",
      "type": "ASSSAA"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am processing child objects via a "Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step" and then iterating over them..

I then Resolve the Sitecore item for the child object - in this case to a seperate Sitecore folder. In my mapping for child object, I need to set the value of a Sitecore field to the id of the parent object i.e. ParentId to "XXX" but at this stage I don't have access to the the id of the parent object as the "Copy Object..." pipeline step is using the json only for child objects. How can I set the value of this parent id field inside my child object?

Answer (score 1):

Add Apply Mapping pipeline step to take parent id and set to child.

Example:

[image]

Configuration for Apply Mapping

[image]

Configuration for Apply Mapping for Parent Id

[image]

In the apply mapping for parent Id you can accessing to the parent object selection **Pipeline Context Parent Source** and assign corresponded Mapping Set configuration.